# PHP & MySQL form. Adding empty row

Tags: php, mysql, forms, row

I am having a problem with PHP from that adds data to MYSQL database :

```
<?php require("config/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require("includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$error='';// zmienna do błędów

if(isset($_POST[submit])){



 if(trim($_POST[username])=='' || strlen(trim($_POST[username])) < 6 ||strlen(trim($_POST[username])) >12){


     $error.="Name must be between 6 ad 12 chars<br />";

 }  

}if($error==''){  // if no error, do a query

    $sql = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET username=\"$username\", password=\"$password\"");




}

    else {

     echo "<span style=color:red>$error</span>";

    }   

    mysql_close($connection);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Add user</h2>

<form action="add.php" method="post">

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></p>
<p>Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password" /></p>
<p> <input type="submit" value="submit  " name="submit" /></p>

</form> 

<a href="index.php">Cancel</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The main problem is when I input username and password here is what I get:

http://i.padsbanger.pl/img/cdf5b5p988ga

For unknown reason it adds an empty row and after that it adds what I have trully inputed into my form. Any help ?

Comment: off topic, but you must protect your database using PDO and parameterized queries.  do not take get or post data and put it into your query.

Comment: As @TimG added -> Please read this re [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: You're not showing us the right part of the code. This code does not print the edit/delete buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are executing the query twice, once on page load and then again on submit

```
$error='';
if(isset($_POST[submit])){
 if(trim($_POST[username])=='' || strlen(trim($_POST[username])) < 6 ||strlen(trim($_POST[username])) >12){
     $error.="Name must be between 6 ad 12 chars<br />";
 }  
}// closes if(isset   *** move this until after the next if statement ***

//this is run everytime as its outside the if(isset block
if($error==''){  // errors is initialised as '' so this will run
    $sql = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO users SET username=\"$username\", password=\"$password\"");
}
```

`if(isset($_POST[submit])){` should be `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

[**SQL Injection** - You should read this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)